# Waiting results from instance of a class passed to a method as parameter

Tags: c#, asynchronous, xamarin.android, async-await, task

This is a confusing matter for me, hope to describe it correctly.
This is in a Xamarin.Android project:

I have a class like this (simplified):

```
    public class FinishedListener : Java.Lang.Object, IabHelper.IOnIabSetupFinishedListener
    {
      public IabResult Data { get; internal set; } = null;

      public void OnIabSetupFinished(IabResult res)
      {
        if (res != null) { Data = res; }
      }
    }
```

and a calling method:

```
    public class Class1
    {
      public void Method1()
      {
        FinishedListener listner = new FinishedListener();
        SomeClass.Init(listner );
        // Do something with "listner.Data.Response"
      }
    }
```

Because Init class works asynchronously, listner.Data will not be available at once.

What's the best way to implement waiting for this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if your Init method is awaitable, assuming it is you can do something like this;

```
 public async void Method1()
  {
    FinishedListener listner = new FinishedListener();
    await SomeClass.Init(listner);
    // Do something with "listner.Data.Response"
  }
```

In case it is non-awaitable do this:

```
  public async void Method1()
  {
    FinishedListener listner = new FinishedListener();
    await Task.Run(()=>{ SomeClass.Init(listner); });  
    // Do something with "listner.Data.Response"
  }
```

When this executes what will happen is that your existing compiler will wait for execution of `await SomeClass.Init(listner);` and then the next line shall execute.

Comment: actually no. It's a void method.